# adding partition in a existing table in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

I have an existing table and in that table I have the partition like this:

```
partition DEC052015 values less than (TO_DATE(' 2015-12-06 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'));
```

now I want to add partition **from dec 06 2015 to march 30 2016** without adding them manually like

```
alter table table_name 
   add partition DEC062015 
   values less than (TO_DATE(' 2015-12-07 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'));
```

and so on.

Can someone give the query to **auto update** it or **a loop** to do it fast.

Comment: For Oracle 11.1 and upper there are [Interval partitioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/part_admin001.htm#BAJHFFBE)

Comment: can u plz share it..thank u :)